# shrinker does not respect condition

Tags: f#, fscheck

I am trying to implement a generator and a shrinker with fscheck that would produce two strings not empty and different to one another. In order to do so, I use the following code :

```
let nonWhiteSpaceString s =
    not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace s) && not (String.exists ((=) '\000') s)

type DifferentNonWhiteSpace = | DifferentNonWhiteSpace of NonWhiteSpaceString*NonWhiteSpaceString

type DifferentNonWhiteSpaceGen = 
    static member DifferentNonWhiteSpace() =

        let generator =
            generate<String>
            |> Gen.two
            |> Gen.filter (fun (a,b) -> nonWhiteSpaceString a && nonWhiteSpaceString b && a<>b )
            |> Gen.map (fun (a,b) -> DifferentNonWhiteSpace((NonWhiteSpaceString a),NonWhiteSpaceString(b)))
        let shrinker (DifferentNonWhiteSpace(a,b)) = 

            let seqA = a.Get.ToCharArray() 
                        |> shrink 
                        |> Seq.map String 
            b.Get.ToCharArray() 
            |> shrink 
            |> Seq.map  String  
            |> Seq.map2 (fun x y -> if x <> y then Some(DifferentNonWhiteSpace(NonWhiteSpaceString x,NonWhiteSpaceString y)) else  None) seqA
            |> Seq.choose id

        fromGenShrink (generator,shrinker)
```

I use it like in tests as follows:

```
testProperty "calculate Xml against different Prefix should produce youpi" <| fun (DifferentNonWhiteSpace(prefix1,prefix2)) -> 
  let xml1 = createXml <| changePrefix prefix1
  let xml2 = createXml <| changePrefix prefix2
  let actual = calculate xml1 xml2
  Expect.equal actual Youpi "return youpi"
```

Generator seems ok, but shrinker does not what I expected it to do :

> Failed after 1 test. Parameters:
>           DifferentNonWhiteSpace (NonWhiteSpaceString "K",NonWhiteSpaceString "▲")
>   Shrunk 3 times to:
>           **DifferentNonWhiteSpace (NonWhiteSpaceString "a",NonWhiteSpaceString "a")**
>   Result:
>           Exception
>     Expecto.AssertException: return Bouh.

I should not have the same value in the shrunk data :

> DifferentNonWhiteSpace (NonWhiteSpaceString "a",NonWhiteSpaceString
>   "a")

Could someone point me out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

[edit]
Actually, I also have issues with the generator.

```
Failed after 11 tests. Parameters:
        DifferentNonWhiteSpace (NonWhiteSpaceString "v",NonWhiteSpaceString "v")
Result:
        Exception
  Expecto.AssertException: return Bouh.
```

it is weird...

Comment: This may be a bug in FsCheck. You may have more luck if you post it to the FsCheck repro on github. It's been a while that I used FsCheck myself, so I may not be able to help you with this specific case.

Comment: I will file an issue in github. Thx for your comment

Comment: I think FsCheck is just not picking up your custom `Arbitrary` instance. I'm not so familiar with expecto - is there a parameter for `testProperty` or similar that allows you to pass in an `Arbitrary` or some such? If you like I can also answer with an example in "pure" FsCheck.

Comment: `testPropertyWithConfig` should work I think, the config is hopefully the same as FsCheck's and so has a field for passing in types with overrides, i.e. try `testPropertyWithConfig {  FsCheckConfig.defaultConfig with Arbitrary = typeof<DifferentNonWhiteSpaceGen> }`

Comment: this is it. How stupid I am. I forgot to use "testPropertyWithConfig config"  in order to use the correct abitraries instead of "testProperty"

Answer (score 1):

Thx to Kurt Schelfthout comment , I have forgotten to use

```
testPropertyWithConfig config ....
```

instead of

```
testProperty ....
```

in order to use my custom arbitraries :

```
let config = 
        {   
            FsCheckConfig.defaultConfig with 
                arbitrary= 
                    [
                        typeof<DifferentNonWhiteSpaceGen>
                    ]
        }
```

Comment: Glad you found it eventually, and good to know it wasn't a bug in FsCheck after all :).